# Javascript or webgl performance bounds

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl

I'm exploring the question how many (textured) 2D shapes WebGL can animate, given the need to reconstruct the whole scene in Javascript for every frame (due to zooming, we need to discard shapes getting too big, and add shapes which are just zooming in). The initial idea is thus to keep the camera fixed, and implement zooming, panning, moving solely by manipulating the shapes.

We would like to go up to 1.000 (better 10.000) moderately complex shapes: 2D, no bevels, but with rounded corners, circles, frames, and text. (We plan to do text by two textured triangles per letter - tetxure atlas, I heard it called.) To make it worse, the resulting animation should also be usable on a tablet (no phones).

WebGL is completely capable of animating the resulting number of triangles, as many examples show. However, my impression is that Javascript is not capable of constructing a scene containing 10.000 triangles in 30fps. (Estimation: ten triangles per shape for 1.000 shapes, this is the lowest bound for the shape complexity and the number of shapes.)

I've seen side remarks on how many triangles can be animated without stuttering ([e.g., here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516187/performance-of-webgl-and-opengl)), but I'd like to hear your opinion:

Can 10.000 to 100.000 triangles be animated smoothly on a desktop WebGL implementation at all?

ADDITION (in response to a question in the comments)

Yes, using requestAnimationFrame.

Calculate the buffer arrays in frame (i.e., during rendering).

Currently using drawArrays, once per frame, as I read this was important to performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance all depends on how your application is made.

There is no real limitation with JS. But there is an important limitation with WebGL (OpenGL ES) : index array is a Uint16Array, so you can't index more than 65536 vertices per draw. But you can do multiple draws per frame to solve it.

Comment: Well, there's an WebGL extension (available on my Lenovo with FF and Chrome) which extends that limit above 65000. See webglacademy.com, example 6-Import from Blender, which features a dragon with 300.000 vertices, if I counted correctly. The magic is in `var EXT = GL.getExtension("OES_element_index_uint") ||
        GL.getExtension("MOZ_OES_element_index_uint") ||
        GL.getExtension("WEBKIT_OES_element_index_uint");'

Comment: I didn't know about that. Does it work with tablets ? The FPS will then all depend on your code. Are you using requestAnimationFrame ? Where do you calculate the buffer arrays (in frame or in a worker ?) ? How many times are you calling drawElements / drawArrays per frame ?

Comment: SOME FINDINGS (before it's closed :-) If you're smart about buffering and Javascript performance, all is well: 
(1) Don't use typed arrays. Use pre-allocated native arrays: Writing to an existing array (array[i] = ..) is quicker than pushing items to the array. 
(2) (obvious, I guess) I use different buffers for positions, colors, textures, texture coordinates, and only positions change often. Pass only buffers with changes to WebGL. 
With these, I get 30fps for around 250.000 colored textured vertices (Chrome and FF, on laptop). That's enough for my scenario. 
Thanks for your patience.